# ExtJS 3.4.0 Wait for Ajax Response

Tags: ajax, extjs, request

I need to assign the response value for return it in a Javascript function using ExtJS 3.4.0 library, the function naturally terminates without waiting for ajax response so the value of count is always zero, I need to know if I can do it this way or if there is an alternative.

Thanks

```
function test() {
    var count = 0;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            count = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        }
    });

    if (count > 1) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add return statement in you success function :

```
function test() {
    var count = 0;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: "/Controller/Action",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(response) {
            count = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            if (count > 1) {
               this.other(false);
            }
            this.other(true);
        },
        scope: this
    }); 
},

function other(param){
     console.log(param);
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Riku thanks for your answer, along the way you mention the return is only for the success function but not the function wrapper.
Any other idea?